# A action recebe um atributo do componente classe porém não entra no reducer react-redux

Tags: react

Estou fazendo um projeto simplório com React e Redux para treinar e pego um atributo (string) que está no store através de uma função do componente faço um processamento nessa string e mando para action que deve enviar ao reducer e salvá-lo em um atributo da store. Porém essa string chega até a action mas não entra no reducer, o que pode estar errado? Códigos abaixo.

Componente:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { msgChanged, resultChanged, clear } from '../actions/messageAction';

import Button from './button';

class Message extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.encrypt = this.encrypt.bind(this);
    this.decrypt = this.decrypt.bind(this);
}

encrypt() {
    let step = this.props.counter.step;
    let msg = this.props.message.msg.toUpperCase();
    let alpha = this.props.message.alpha;
    let resultAux = '';
    for(let j = 0; j < msg.length; j++) {
        if(msg[j] === ' ') {
            resultAux += ' ';
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
                if(msg[j] === alpha[i]) {
                    let num = (i + step) % alpha.length
                    resultAux += alpha[num];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    resultChanged(resultAux);
}

decrypt() {
    let step = this.props.counter.step;
    let msg = this.props.message.msg.toUpperCase();
    let alpha = this.props.message.alpha;
    let resultAux = '';
    for(let j = 0; j < msg.length; j++) {
        if(msg[j] === ' ') {
            resultAux += ' ';
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
                if(msg[j] === alpha[i]) {
                    let num = (i - step) % alpha.length
                    resultAux += alpha[num];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    resultChanged(resultAux);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={this.props.msgChanged} type='text' value={this.props.message.msg} />
            <Button action={this.encrypt} label='Criptografar' />
            <Button action={this.decrypt} label='Descriptografar' />
            <Button action={this.props.clear} label='Apagar' />
            <p>{this.props.message.result}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

};

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ message: state.message, counter: state.counter });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ msgChanged,   resultChanged, clear }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Message);
```

Action:

```
export const resultChanged = function(resultMsg) {
  console.log('action', resultMsg);
  return {
    type: 'RESULT_CHANGED',
    payload: resultMsg
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
msg: '',
result: '',
alpha: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

}

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action.type, action.payload);
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'MSG_CHANGED':
        return { ...state, msg: action.payload };
        break;
    case 'RESULT_CHANGED':
        console.log('reducer', action.payload)
        return { ...state, result: action.payload };
        break;
    case 'CLEAR':
        return { ...state, msg: '' };
        break;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dê um `console.log({ ...state, result: action.payload })` dentro do RESULT_CHANGED case pra ver se aparece alguma coisa. Se aparecer, então tá tudo certo no reducer e o problema é quando você fizer o mapStateToProps.

Comment: Se você só tiver um único reducer (o que você escreveu), então o problema é porque você usa `{ message: state.message, counter: state.counter }`, mas no reducer você seta "msg" e não `message`. E no result changed, voce seta `result`, que nao esta incluido no mapStateToProps.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente como falei ele não entra no reducer, coloquei o console.log só para tirar a dúvida mas não acontece nada. O console.log que ele tem na action está executando mas depois para por aí.

Quanto ao reducer eu estou usando dois:

`import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import counterReducer from '../reducer/counterReducer';
import messageReducer from '../reducer/messageReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counter: counterReducer,
    message: messageReducer
});

export default rootReducer;`

Comment: Os outros actions que usam o mesmo reducer funcionam corretamente, só esse que recebe uma variável para executar que não funciona, essa variável vem de uma função dentro do componente de classe. Já mostrei para outras pessoas e por enquanto está um mistério...

Answer (score 1):

Um dos possíveis problemas é que você não está usando Object.assign no seu reducers:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'MSG_CHANGED':
        return Object.assign({}, state, { msg: action.payload });
    case 'RESULT_CHANGED':
        return Object.assign({}, state, { result: action.payload });
    case 'CLEAR':
        return Object.assign({}, state, { msg: '' });
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

O jeito que você está implementando pode estar mutando seu state.

Para te ajudar com problemas como esse te aconselho utilizar a biblioteca

> redux-immutable-state-invariant

A palavra break não é necessária depois da palavra return;

Seria interessante você utilizar um lint como o eslint ou o prettier que vão te ajudar a codificar melhor.

Comment: Na verdade não é isso, o problema foi resolvido utilizando um simples this.props.resultChanged(resultAux) dentro do componente.

Quanto ao break ele é importante que seja usado pois pode acontecer algum bug que deixe vazar a instrução, veja em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Obrigado de qualquer formar pela tentativa de ajuda.

Comment: Com relação ao break, na documentação que você enviou da mozilla não mostra nada com o break após um return. Esse link do eslint mostra exatamente o que eu estou falando: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unreachable